# Obtener usuario de Windows donde se está ejecutando Windows Form

Tags: c#, windows-forms

¿Cómo puedo obtener el usuario de Windows donde se está ejecutando mi sistema Windows form C#?

Tengo este código:

```
private void txtuser_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e){
    if (txtuser.Text == "USUARIO"){
        txtuser.Text = "";
        txtuser.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(104, 159, 56);
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿Y cuál es la pregunta? ¿CUál es el problema con ese bloque de código? ¿QUé quieres hacer con él? Poner un bloque de código sin decir qué se quiere, con qué datos y qué debe resultar, es una mala forma de preguntar, pues no se entiende. Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el funcionamiento y ya de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
Por otro lado, estaría bien que le echaras un vistazo a [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tus preguntas reciban respuesta cuanto antes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Podrias usar el

[Environment.UserName](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.username?view=netframework-4.5)

este retorna el usuario que esta autenticado en el sistema operativo

Comment: muchas gracias!!!!

Comment: Procura no dar respuestas que sólo sea un enlace. Cuántas veces un enlace de documentación ha cambiado y se rompe? Si eso pasa, esta respuesta ya no le sirve a nadie en el futuro

Answer (score 2):

Utilice este código

```
string userName = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
```

Comment: ¿Por qué este código resuelve el problema? Procura reseñar brevemente lo que este código hace para resolver la pregunta.

Comment: Hola Oscar, como te indica otro usuario, las publicaciones que son sólo código se consideran de baja calidad y no suelen ser de ayuda para otros usuarios. Sería bueno que añadieras algo más de información: ¿qué es lo que hace este código? ¿cómo resuelve el problema? ¿algún enlace a documentación sobre el mismo? Lee [answer] para más información.

Comment: disculpen lo tendré encuenta